# pytorch installation conda vs pip import error (macOs)

Tags: macos, python, environment-variables, anaconda

Currently, I have pytorch installed from this, which appears to be from anaconda.

```
╰─ pip install torch torchvision
Requirement already satisfied: torch in /Users/PLEB/opt/anaconda3/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.8/site-packages (1.9.0)
Requirement already satisfied: torchvision in /Users/PLEB/opt/anaconda3/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.8/site-packages (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: typing_extensions in /Users/PLEB/opt/anaconda3/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from torch) (3.10.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /Users/PLEB/opt/anaconda3/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from torchvision) (1.21.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow>=5.3.0 in /Users/PLEB/opt/anaconda3/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from torchvision) (8.2.0)
```

However, I have trouble to `import torch` and do simple pytorch functions on a simple python script when done through my desktop, like creating a simple `foo.py` file in VS Code. (which I assume uses the python I had installed locally ?)

The error says it is not found.

Currently, I can only do this (see below) via Anaconda Navigator, which allows me to `import torch` in the terminal successfully but I cannot still create a file and run `import torch` etc

`/Users/XXXX/opt/anaconda3/bin/activate && conda activate /Users/XXXX/opt/anaconda3/envs/pytorch;`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that vscode is using the right python when executing your script. It might not be using the Anaconda python but instead, the python installed by default on your system.

That should be shown at the bottom left of the vscode editor, assuming that you have the python extension installed. It also allows changing the python used to run your script.